# angular bootstrap datepicker mismatch between view and model

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using angular bootstrap timepicker.
The problem I'm facing is that I have a mismatch between the view and the model.
As you can see from the example, I chose 2015-05-07 but the model is a day behind.

```
<div dir="ltr" class="col-md-3 datePickerComponent">
                <div>{{payments.user.start_dt}}</div>
                    <span dir="rtl" class="datePickerLabel">
                     תאריך התחלה 
                    </span>&nbsp;
                    <p class="input-group">
                      <input ng-disabled="true" dir="rtl" ng-change="payments.GetPayments()" type="text" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="dd-MM-yyyy" ng-model="payments.user.start_dt" is-open="payments.opened_start"  />
                      <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="payments.open_start($event)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
                      </span>
                    </p>
                </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the date filter to the value in your view

```
<div>{{payments.user.start_dt | date : format : timezone}}</div>
```

e.g.

```
<div>{{payments.user.start_dt | date : longDate}}</div>
```

see [AngularJS Docs - Date Filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date)

Comment: I just ran into the same problem. but why does this difference occur ?

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this issue here 
[Angular UI bootstrap date mismatch between model & datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37827372/angular-ui-bootstrap-date-mismatch-between-model-datepicker/37849456#37849456)

Adding the date filter to the view will just solve the problem of display.
If you are sending it to a Rest API you would still get a day behind on the server.

To solve it, you will have to add this to your date picker.

```
ng-model-options="{timezone: 'UTC'}"
```