# Angular UI bootstrap date mismatch between model & datepicker

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap

See this Plunkr  :

http://plnkr.co/edit/gSTqtxfcEjrYLt1mIzVD?p=preview

I have taken this from an eg.  given at https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ for a demo of date picker.

In the heading, **My Date** when I am selecting a date 2016-06-15 from the date picker, the model which is bound shows date as 2016-06-14.
so always there is a mismatch of 1 day.

This post [angular bootstrap datepicker mismatch between view and model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30070556/angular-bootstrap-datepicker-mismatch-between-view-and-model/30070762#comment63117015_30070762)
suggested to apply date filter to the view.

However, it is only a patch up as when I am posting to an api, I still get 2016-06-14 on the server.

Is this a bug or is there some work around for it ?

**HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.3.3.js"></script>
    <script src="example.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>

<style>
  .full button span {
    background-color: limegreen;
    border-radius: 32px;
    color: black;
  }
  .partially button span {
    background-color: orange;
    border-radius: 32px;
    color: black;
  }
</style>
<div ng-controller="DatepickerPopupDemoCtrl">
    <pre>Selected date is: <em>{{dt | date:'fullDate' }}</em></pre>

    <h4>Popup</h4>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <p class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dt" is-open="popup1.opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" alt-input-formats="altInputFormats" />
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open1()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
          </span>
        </p>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-6">
        <p class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup ng-model="dt" is-open="popup2.opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open2()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
          </span>
        </p>
      </div>

      <br/>
      <h2> My Date</h2>
      Date is : {{dt1 | date : 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}
Real Date is : {{dt1}}
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <p class="input-group">

          <input type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup ng-model="dt1" is-open="popup3.opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open3()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
          </span>
        </p>
      </div>

      <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="dt1 | date"  />

    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <label>Format: <span class="muted-text">(manual alternate <em>{{altInputFormats[0]}}</em>)</span></label> <select class="form-control" ng-model="format" ng-options="f for f in formats"><option></option></select>
      </div>
    </div>

    <hr />
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-info" ng-click="today()">Today</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" ng-click="setDate(2009, 7, 24)">2009-08-24</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" ng-click="clear()">Clear</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" ng-click="toggleMin()" uib-tooltip="After today restriction">Min date</button>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Script :**

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('DatepickerPopupDemoCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.today = function() {
    $scope.dt = new Date();
  };
  $scope.today();



  $scope.clear = function() {
    $scope.dt = null;
  };

  $scope.inlineOptions = {
    customClass: getDayClass,
    minDate: new Date(),
    showWeeks: true
  };

  $scope.dateOptions = {
    dateDisabled: disabled,
    formatYear: 'yy',
    maxDate: new Date(2020, 5, 22),
    minDate: new Date(),
    startingDay: 1
  };

  // Disable weekend selection
  function disabled(data) {
    var date = data.date,
      mode = data.mode;
    return mode === 'day' && (date.getDay() === 0 || date.getDay() === 6);
  }

  $scope.toggleMin = function() {
    $scope.inlineOptions.minDate = $scope.inlineOptions.minDate ? null : new Date();
    $scope.dateOptions.minDate = $scope.inlineOptions.minDate;
  };

  $scope.toggleMin();

  $scope.open1 = function() {
    $scope.popup1.opened = true;
  };

  $scope.open2 = function() {
    $scope.popup2.opened = true;
  };

    $scope.open3 = function() {
    $scope.popup3.opened = true;
  };

  $scope.setDate = function(year, month, day) {
    $scope.dt = new Date(year, month, day);
  };

  $scope.formats = ['dd-MMMM-yyyy', 'yyyy/MM/dd', 'dd.MM.yyyy', 'shortDate'];
  $scope.format = $scope.formats[0];
  $scope.altInputFormats = ['M!/d!/yyyy'];

  $scope.popup1 = {
    opened: false
  };

  $scope.popup2 = {
    opened: false
  };



  $scope.popup3 = {
    opened: false
  };


  var tomorrow = new Date();
  tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1);
  var afterTomorrow = new Date();
  afterTomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1);
  $scope.events = [
    {
      date: tomorrow,
      status: 'full'
    },
    {
      date: afterTomorrow,
      status: 'partially'
    }
  ];

  function getDayClass(data) {
    var date = data.date,
      mode = data.mode;
    if (mode === 'day') {
      var dayToCheck = new Date(date).setHours(0,0,0,0);

      for (var i = 0; i < $scope.events.length; i++) {
        var currentDay = new Date($scope.events[i].date).setHours(0,0,0,0);

        if (dayToCheck === currentDay) {
          return $scope.events[i].status;
        }
      }
    }

    return '';
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by adding this in the model.

```
ng-model-options="{timezone: 'UTC'}"
```

See the updated plunkr here.

http://plnkr.co/edit/x0WLHNG7l5VBRU5tN8Q1?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

I think, time zone is causing this issue. Please refer the below URL:

https://gist.github.com/weberste/354a3f0a9ea58e0ea0de