# will conversion of timestamp to date in different timezones returns different date and time?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datetime, timestamp

I am trying to convert my current date into timestamp and send it to API to save it. When I try to retrive the timestamp back from API and convert it to date, it is retriving coorectly.

The issue is when I send current timestamp to API and if a person in singapore fetch the same timestamp from API and try to convert to date, It shows (date and time I have sent to API)+2.30hr.

I use **new Date(timestamp)** in javascript to convert timestamp into date.

Similarly it differs to different timezone.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Try this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37827372/angular-ui-bootstrap-date-mismatch-between-model-datepicker/37827722#37827722

Answer (score 0):

You can use UTC time to standardize between various locations and send it in your api, and when someone wants to work in singapore receive the datetime in UTC and then convert it to his local time-zone.

```
var utcDate = new Date(Date.UTC(96, 11, 1, 0, 0, 0));
```

The constructor of Date.UTC

```
Date.UTC(year, month[, day[, hour[, minute[, second[, millisecond]]]]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Unix like timestamps in Javascript are the number of milliseconds since Jan 1 1970 with no time zone offset. `Date.now()` returns such a timestamp.

If you send "your date and time" to the API as a timestamp, retrieve it and convert back into "date and time" in a browser on your PC, the conversion back will be from UTC into local time as defined by the local zone setting of your PC.  Somebody 2.5 hours west of you, with a local time 2.5 hours later, will convert the same UTC timestamp into a local time value 2.5 hours later than yours.

How to resolve the issue depends on what needs to be achieved. Should global users see timestamps in **your timezone**,  **UTC**, **their timezone**, a **timezone specified on the website**, or **relative to a given location**, such as the departure and arrival airports of aircraft flights? This needs to be decided first, before looking into Date object methods with "UTC" in their names :-).

---

In response to comment of using OP's timezone:

If your location does not use daylight saving, you could include your fixed timezone offset in page script and use it in conjunction with users' timezone to produce a date and time string matching your local time of creation. A problem if daylight saving is introduced to your area in the future.

For daylight saving, you could add your easterly time zone offset in milliseconds to a Date.now() time stamp, store the result in the API, retrieve the timestamp and convert into a date and time string using the .getUTCxxx methods inherited from [`Date.prototype`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/prototype). Such a conversion should match your local time when the timestamp was created. The method may have valid criticisms but at least should meet with requirements!

Ideally the UTC timestamp would be stored unchanged, and the local timezone offset of the creator stored as well.

Comment: I want to see my timezone date and time after conversion in all other locations(different timezones)

Comment: You should also store your timezone in API then. And when you're getting data, use this timezone.